# Is there a standardized maximum variable binary width that an if statement can evaluate?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Is the maximum variable width that an if statement can evaluate implementation specific. Or can a compiler force a cast on a variable to a another type such as a boolean to be evaluated by an if statement. Consider the following code below, as well as the output on my machine. I ask because I would like to reliably distribute a library using for use on a number of different machines including arm, mips, amd86, x86 etc. Please note that I understand that native integer types do not always reach 64/32/16 bit width.

Furthermore if it is defined, then how exactly is it defined?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <bitset>
int main() {

// Initialises variables with a single binary 1 in the left most place.
uint8_t eight_bit = (~0) << (8 - 1);
uint16_t sixteen_bit = (~0) << (16 - 1);
uint32_t thirty_two_bit = (~0) << (32 - 1);
uint64_t sixty_four_bit = (~0) << (64 - 1);


std::cout << "The 8 bit integer is equal to: " 
    << std::bitset<8>(eight_bit) << "\n";
std::cout << "The 16 bit integer is equal to: " 
    << std::bitset<16>(sixteen_bit) << "\n";
std::cout << "The 32 bit integer is equal to: " 
    << std::bitset<32>(thirty_two_bit) << "\n";
std::cout << "The 64 bit integer is equal to: " 
    << std::bitset<64>(sixty_four_bit) << "\n";


if (eight_bit)      
    std::cout << "8 bit variable considered true." << "\n";

if (sixteen_bit)    
    std::cout << "16 bit variable considered true." << "\n";

if (thirty_two_bit) 
    std::cout << "32 bit variable considered true." << "\n";

if (sixty_four_bit) 
    std::cout << "64 bit variable considered true." << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
The 8 bit integer is equal to: 10000000
The 16 bit integer is equal to: 1000000000000000
The 32 bit integer is equal to: 10000000000000000000000000000000
The 64 bit integer is equal to: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
8 bit variable considered true.
16 bit variable considered true.
32 bit variable considered true.
64 bit variable considered true.
```

Comment: You have a giant pile of undefined behavior there with the shifts. I'm also not sure I understand the question.

Comment: An if() statement can evaluate any expression that evaluates to a bool. Any numerical type evaluates to a bool, via a comparison with 0, so the if statement will support any integer type supported on the target implementation. Then we come to pointers, which, in a bool context are also compared to 0. Then we come to an arbitrary class, if it has a suitable bool operator. The if statement is pretty versatile, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: `~0` is not equal to `1`. Just use `1 << (8-1)`.

Comment: @RSahu It does exactly the same thing as the other bits are simply lost.

Comment: I've had problems with integer promotion on shifting in the past.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25902721/1553090

Comment: @T.C. The idea behind the shift was simply an easy way to get a one in the furthest binary position to the left. This is simply so that I can demonstrate that if a cast to a boolean where to occur then the if statement would evaluate as a false because the cast integer would not have any bits that could be represented in a boolean variable.

Comment: @bruffalobill if you're interested in writing portable code, learning which shifts are portable is a good start. (These ones are not)

Comment: `(~0U) << 63` would have been portable, but this isn't.

Comment: @MSalters not so; if `unsigned int` is 32-bit then it shifts by more than the width of the type

Comment: @M.M : You're indeed right, I managed to miss the other required suffix there. You need `U` as left-shifing a negative value is UB straight away, but you still have to abide by the other rules as well. Adding LL to give `(~0ULL) << 63` makes it safe on that count as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `if(X)`, is that it behaves as if there were a temporary created by this definition:

```
bool temp(X);
```

and then iff `temp` is `true`, the test succeeds.  If that declaration would be ill-formed then the `if`-statement is ill-formed.

Conversion from integer types to `bool` is defined that zero gives `false` and everything else gives `true`.

(To be clear, the answer to your question is that any type implictily convertible to `bool` may be evaluated by an `if` statement).

---

NB. `(~0) << (8 - 1);` etc. in your question causes undefined behaviour. Informally, left-shifting a `1` into the sign bit is undefined (which implies that all left-shifts of negative numbers are undefined).

Also, `(~0) << (64 - 1);` would cause UB due to shifting by greater than the width of the type, if you have 32-bit ints.

To avoid this, start with `1ULL` instead of `~0`, or do something like `uint64_t x = INT64_MIN;`. (With the latter approach you could use a template to find the value via `std::numeric_limits`).

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard (C++11) defines up to 64 bit integral types:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

However, some implementations can go up to 128 bits.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx

Presumably a particular implementation could define their own extension to go arbitrarily large.

So, if you want to stick with portable C++ standard types, stick to 64-bit and below as defined in the C++ spec.  If the native size is smaller, a standard compiler will provide the implementation to support the larger size (possibly at a performance penalty) by combining smaller native words.  (e.g. creating a 64-bit integer from 2 32-bit words on a 32-bit platform.)

If you are really trying to ask "how do I find out the largest native size on my platform?" that's a different question.