# Typecast four bytes to a 4 byte int

Tags: c++, casting, byte

If the string is:

```
char message[] = "HI THERE";
```

How would I take the first four bytes (`"HI T"`) and typecast them to a 4 byte int?

Total value should equal `1411402056`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safe way to do it which will always work is to just shift each byte individually:

```
uint32_t i = (uint8_t(message[0]) << 24) | (uint8_t(message[1]) << 16) | (uint8_t(message[2]) << 8) | uint8_t(message[3]);
```

You might need to reverse the order of the bytes depending on the endianess of your string.

You may also be able to simply reinterpret cast to an integer depending on the endianess of the string matching the endianess of your processor, whether the string is aligned to the correct byte boundary etc:

```
Int i = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(message);
```

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is an aliasing violation and OP seems to want the result in the opposite order from the your first example. "*Endianess of your string*" makes no sense to me. The string is accessed element/byte-wise and that order does not depend on endianess.

Comment: Be aware that the first solution won't necessarily extend to a solution for 64-bit integers without typecasting.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25902721/1553090

Comment: `int i = (message[3] << 24) | (message[2] << 16) | (message[1] << 8) | (message[0]);` does give the correct value. What would be the best way to cast it back to characters?

Comment: @sewyut Simply reverse the bit shifts: `message[3] = (char)(i >> 24); message[2] = (char)(i >> 16); message[1] = (char)(i >> 8); message[0] = (char)i;`

Comment: The first one causes undefined behaviour if any of the character values are negative

Comment: Any idea on how to not get undefined behavior if the value is say a negative? Because it doesn't convert correctly if it is a negative value.

Comment: @walnut the string itself may not have an endianess but the data held within it certainly does

Comment: @sewyut casting to unsigned first will fix issues with negative characters

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```cpp
int32_t num = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(message);
```

But this is technically a violation of Strict Aliasing.  A safer way is:

```cpp
int32_t num;
memcpy(&num, message, sizeof(num));
```

Though, to be really safe, you should use the bit-shifting approach described in Alan Birtles's answer.

You might have to swap the order of the `int`'s bytes afterwards, depending on the endian of your system.

Comment: `int32_t` or `uint32_t` would be preferable to `int`.