# How can a double be converted to bytes to be stored in c++?

Tags: c++, double, c++20, uint8t, uint64

I am trying to write a program that can take a list of a specific type for example a `double` or `float` and convert it into bytes and write it to a file that can be converted back into that original list. I came up with the following `struct`s and functions. It works for a `float` list, however, it does not if it is a list of `doubles` and I am trying to understand why.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct writer{
    static constexpr size_t Size = sizeof(T); 
    //the size to determing if it needs to be converted to uint16_t, uint32_t, etc...
    static constexpr bool U = std::conditional<std::is_unsigned_v<T>, std::true_type, 
          typename std::conditional<std::is_same_v<T, float>, std::true_type,
          typename std::conditional<std::is_same_v<T, double>, std::true_type, std::false_type>::type >::type >::type::value;
    //this is used to determine if the storing_num variable needs to be stored as unsigned or not
    using value_t = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 1, 
          std::conditional_t<U, uint8_t, int8_t>,
          std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 2,
          std::conditional_t<U, uint16_t, int16_t>,
          std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 4,
          std::conditional_t<U, uint32_t, int32_t>, //by default the only options are 1, 2, 4, and 8
          std::conditional_t<U, uint64_t, int64_t> > > >;
    //the value that will either be entered or bit_casted to (shown in convert_num function)
    value_t storing_num;
    using my_byte = std::conditional_t<U == true, uint8_t, int8_t>;
    std::array<my_byte, Size> _arr;
    bool convert_num(T inp){
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(value_t), "T and value_t need to be the same size");
        if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<T, value_t>){
            storing_num = std::bit_cast<value_t>(inp);
        }else{
            storing_num = inp;
        }

        auto begin = _arr.begin();
        for(int32_t i = _arr.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i, ++begin){
            *begin = ((storing_num >> (i << 3)) & 0xFF);
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool write(std::ostream& outfile){
        auto begin = _arr.cbegin();
        auto end = _arr.cend();
        for(;begin != end; ++begin)
            outfile << (char)(*begin);
        return true;
    }

};
```

The following can be used to write a `float` or `uint32_t` to a text file successfully. The following can be used to read one of the numbers back in:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct reader{
    static constexpr size_t Size = sizeof(T);
    static constexpr bool U = std::conditional<std::is_unsigned_v<T>, std::true_type, 
          typename std::conditional<std::is_same_v<T, float>, std::true_type,
          typename std::conditional<std::is_same_v<T, double>, std::true_type, std::false_type>::type >::type >::type::value;
    using value_t = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 1, 
          std::conditional_t<U, uint8_t, int8_t>,
          std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 2,
          std::conditional_t<U, uint16_t, int16_t>,
          std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 4,
          std::conditional_t<U, uint32_t, int32_t>, //by default the only options are 1, 2, 4, and 8
          std::conditional_t<U, uint64_t, int64_t> > > >;
    value_t outp;
    std::array<int8_t, Size> _arr;
    bool add_nums(std::ifstream& in){
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(value_t), "T and value_t need to be the same size");
        _arr[0] = in.get();
        if(_arr[0] == -1)
            return false;
        for(uint32_t i = 1; i < _arr.size(); ++i){
            _arr[i] = in.get();
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool convert(){
        if(std::any_of(_arr.cbegin(), _arr.cend(), [](int v){return v == -1;}))
            return false;
        outp = 0;
        if(U){
            auto begin = _arr.cbegin();
            for(int32_t i = _arr.size()-1; i >= 0; i--, ++begin){
                outp += ((uint8_t)(*begin) << (i * 8));
            }
            return true;
        }
        auto begin = _arr.cbegin();
        for(int32_t i = _arr.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i, ++begin)
            outp += ((*begin) << (i << 3));
        return true;
    }
};
```

Then I use the following functions to iterate over a text file and read/write to said file:

```
template<typename T>
void read_list(T* begin, const char* filename){
    reader<T> my_reader;
    std::ifstream in(filename);
    if(in.is_open()){
        while(in.good()){
            if(!my_reader.add_nums(in))
                break;
            if(!my_reader.convert()){
                std::cerr << "error reading, got -1 from num reading " << filename;
                return;
            }
            if(std::is_same_v<T, typename reader<T>::value_t >) *begin = my_reader.outp;
            else *begin = std::bit_cast<T>(my_reader.outp);
            ++begin;

        }
    }
    if(!in.eof() && in.fail()){
        std::cerr << "error reading " << filename;
        return;
    }
    in.close();
    return; 
}

template<typename T>
void write_list(T* begin, T* end, const char* filename){
    writer<T> my_writer;
    std::ofstream outfile(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    for(;begin != end; ++begin){
        my_writer.convert_num(*begin);
        my_writer.write(outfile);
    }
}
```

For example, the following would work as expected:

```
void write_float_vector(){
    std::vector<float> my_floats = {4.981, 832.991, 33.5, 889.56, 99.8191232, 88.192};
    std::cout<<"my_floats: " << my_floats<<std::endl;
    write_list(&my_floats[0], &my_floats[my_floats.size()], "binary_save/float_try.nt");
}

void read_floats(){
    std::vector<float> my_floats(6);
    read_list(&my_floats[0], "binary_save/float_try.nt");
    std::cout<<"my_floats: " << my_floats<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    write_double_vector();
    std::cout<<"reading..."<<std::endl;
    read_doubles();
}
```

However, if it was converted to `double`s instead of `float`s it fails to read the doubles back in correctly. Why is it failing with doubles?

For example, the following fails based on what is outputted from the `read_doubles` function:

```
void write_double_vector(){
    std::vector<double> my_doubles = {4.981, 832.991, 33.5, 889.56, 99.8191232, 88.192};
    std::cout<<"my_doubles: " << my_doubles<<std::endl;
    write_list(&my_doubles[0], &my_doubles[my_doubles.size()], "binary_save/double_try.nt");
}

void read_doubles(){
    std::vector<double> my_doubles(6);
    read_list(&my_doubles[0], "binary_save/double_try.nt");
    std::cout<<"my_doubles: " << my_doubles<<std::endl;
}
```

### Additional

If you would like to run the code yourself, I added these helper functions, and used the following headers to make it easier to reproduce:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ios>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <bit>


template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v){
    os << "{";
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < v.size()-1; ++i)
        os << v[i]<<',';
    os << v.back() << "}";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Sure they can, but it's then not a "text file".

Comment: What are all the headers like `<sys/_types/_int16_t.h>` for? What do they provide that `<cstdint>`  doesn't already provide?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think so, honestly, I am using nvim as my IDE and it automatically adds those headers when I use those types while coding, I pretty much just copied and pasted. Ill delete it.

Comment: `#include <stdbool.h>` is another of those you don't need. `bool` is a built-in type and `<stdio.h>` should be `<cstdio>` if you even need it. Your code doesn't seem to use it.

Comment: BTW, not sure that `float`/`double` representation is fixed.

Comment: And you should never build a `float` or `double` character-by-character like you seem to do in `reader`. You may create a trap representation. Read `sizeof(double)` `char`s into a buffer and then `std::memcpy` that buffer into the `double`. Also, what is `if (_arr[0] == -1) return false;` supposed to do?

Comment: For anyone who wants to try and make sense of these code snippets, I massaged it into a [mre] that doesn't rely on writing files: https://godbolt.org/z/esEE8c13G

Comment: In `reader` try these replacement functions: `void add_nums(std::istream& in) { in.read(_arr.data(), Size); }` and `void convert() { std::memcpy(&outp, _arr.data(), Size); }`. I'm not sure why they are two separate functions though, but that should make it read a `double` from any `istream` (like an `ifstream`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo They are separate functions because I wanted to handle if there was a wrong number of bytes put into the file for reading, and that was a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building a `float` or `double` character-by-character can cause a trap representation so don't do that. Replace the `_arr` definition with `std::array<char, Size> _arr;` and then use `in.read` + `std::memcpy`:

Example:

```cpp
#include <cstring> // std::memcpy
```

```cpp
// writer:
std::array<char, Size> _arr;

bool convert_num(T inp) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(value_t),
                    "T and value_t need to be the same size");
    std::memcpy(_arr.data(), &inp, Size);
    return true;
}

bool write(std::ostream& outfile) {
    return static_cast<bool>(outfile.write(_arr.data(), Size));
}
```

```cpp
// reader:
std::array<char, Size> _arr;

bool add_nums(std::istream& in) {
    return static_cast<bool>(in.read(_arr.data(), Size));
}

bool convert() {
    std::memcpy(&outp, _arr.data(), Size);
    return true;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/455hWao4n) (originally from Paddy)

Comment: The following does not work for doubles, and makes the float case no longer work as well.

Comment: @SamMoldenha It works if you write them the same way. I added that to the answer. The above are the only changes I needed to make in order to make Paddys test cases work.

Comment: So much cleaner. One point though is that I noticed the original code stores data in reversed byte order. If that's an actual requirement, then memcpy won't help so much. And if this is used for storing integers, then there are the usual cross-platform endianness concerns to worry about.

Comment: @paddy That is true. For endianess, one would have to add a check if the buffer is to be reversed before reading/writing. The most important thing is to use `std::memcpy` when populating `double`s (and `float`s). I've seen _not_ doing it causing all sorts of problems in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your program is the shifting of a smaller data type when you read. You have this in two places (shown together here for clarity, despite being out of context):

```
outp += ((uint8_t)(*begin) << (i * 8));
outp += ((*begin) << (i << 3));
```

In both these cases, the iterator `begin` references an underlying type of `int8_t`. Not only is this a *signed* type, but you're placing trust in the compiler to promote the type to a large enough integer. I actually ran into a similar issue some years ago.

See here: [Undefined high-order of uint64_t while shifting and masking 32-bit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902721/undefined-high-order-of-uint64-t-while-shifting-and-masking-32-bit-values)

The fix is to cast to the correct size before shifting:

```
outp += (((value_t)(uint8_t)*begin) << (i * 8));
outp += (((value_t)(uint8_t)*begin) << (i << 3));
```

I would also like to suggest that you avoid using constructs like `i << 3` instead of `i * 8`. There is simply no need to try and be clever. The compiler will do the right thing, and you're just making the code harder to read. It also lacks consistency, since you're using both forms in the same function.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T4zKjre48).

Answer (score 1):

The only correct (not UB) and `constexpr` way to do it in modern era(C++20) is `std::bit_cast`:

```
#include <bit>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>


double x;
auto x_bytes = std::bit_cast<std::array<std::unit8_t, sizeof(x)>(x);

if (std::endian::native==std::endian::little)
    std::ranges::reverse(x_bytes);

auto y = bit_cast<double>(x_bytes);
```

C++ standard has eliminated all other options. They may work on sime platforms; but being UB, they may break under unspecified conditions and lead to surprise results.
`std::bit_cast` works if the input and output are of same size and trivially copyable. The other options include `reinterpret_cast` which creates problems with strict aliasing rule, `std::memcpy` which is source of bugs due to programmer mistakes, and `union` based type punning which has the worst of both previous ones. `std::bit_cast` has  also the `constexpr` property, which means it can be used in expressions that need be evaluated at compile-time(create a none-type template parameter, or element count of an array...).

Comment: I like this so +1 although _"eliminated all other options"_ may be a bit strong. `memcpy` still works just fine. Perhaps there should also be a `static_assert(std::endian::native==std::endian::big || std::endian::native==std::endian::little);` just to make sure it's not used in a mixed endian environment.

Comment: `memcpy` is C API; it is easy to mix source and destination, or get overlapping meemory ranges that lead to UB. Compiler does use it behind the scene with compile-time proof of safety. But it is not good in user code. The focus of C++ is shifting towards compile-time evaluation. So, regardless of any present caveats, none `constexpr` solutions such as `memcpy` are not 1st rank choice. I can edit the post, but I need to see a single option other than `memcpy`, `union` or `reinterpreted_cast`. You can Google for `memmove` vs `memcpy` to check for the damage due to irresponsible use of the later.

Comment: Endian is a side note. Generlly we need to do nest to host or host to nest conversions when streaming bytes and bit over secondary storage or network. Otherwise mismatched ordering causes problems. I did not intend to draw the focus on endian-ness however.

Comment: I agree with everything except the _"eliminated_" part, but that minor detail is not worth changing (at least not for my sake).